# USB Bluetooth went from fine on plug in to not recognized 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, usb, bluetooth

Today I purchased a USB Bluetooth adapter so I could pair a PS3 Sixaxis controller to my Ubuntu set up. I expected to have to go through some trial and error to get the USB to work properly as it wasn't listed as a Bluetooth adapter with any official support (it's a Targus 4.0 dual-mode micro USB adapter). To my surprised it worked perfectly fine upon plugging it. Everything seemed to work as intended any way - as the Bluetooth icon was present in the upper right of the screen and it could be controlled normally through System Settings. I even got it to recognize the controller without to much of a hassle and was calibrating it for game use.

The problem is I turned off my computer since then, and on re-boot the Bluetooth has been unresponsive. The indicator light on the actual USB device is on so I know it's getting power yet the icon on the top bar is gone and the System Settings are unresponsive. It looks like my computer just stopped recognizing the device but I can't see why.

I've tried rebooting my PC with the adapter unplugged and putting it back in once the system is up and running and I've tried booting my PC with the adapter in different USB slots in case one was faulty.

I've also attempted to switch the software running the device from gnome-bluetooth to bluez but there was no change.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and while I'm not a particularly new user I'm not particularly knowledgeable with code. I tend to just stumble through the forums following the tutorials and suggestions that I can till I either solve my problem or break my OS to the point where I have to do a fresh install so if anyone does have any advice for me I'd appreciate it being as dumbed down as possible.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and type `lsusb` If the device is not listed then unplug it, wait a few seconds, plug it in again, wait a few more seconds and type `dmesg` to see the last kernel log messages. Then edit your question to include the output of the two commands.

Comment: I hadn't managed to stumble through this step in my first attempts at solving the problem. The device is recognized and I've found a work around that enables it. The issue seems to not be in my PC reading the hardware but some issue with Bluez on start up. There must be some kind of software conflict that gums up the works and stops the program from opening properly. If I re-install Bluez through synaptics the Bluetooth functions just as it did the first time I plugged it in.

Comment: That's great. You could put what you did in an answer so that other people can potentially benefit too.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a temporary work around:

The problem seems to be some software conflict that either over-rides or disables Bluez Bluetooth software on boot. I'm currently manually re-installing Bluez through Synaptic every time the problem occurs.

I suspect that a permanent fix involves identifying the conflicting software and replacing/removing it or making some edit to the order in which programs are loaded on start up.